# How to nest multiple counters in css?

Tags: html, css

I would like to nest two different numbering with CSS, in order to obtain automatic numbering looking like this:

1 Section1

1-1 SubSection1

1-2 SubSection1

2 Section2

2-1 SubSection2

2-2 SubSection2

Here is my attempt to achieve that:

```
<head>
    <style>
    body
    {
        counter-reset: sectioncount;
    }

    h1:before
    {
        counter-increment: sectioncount 1;
        counter-reset: subsectioncount;
        content: counter(sectioncount) " ";
    }

    h2:before
    {
        counter-increment: subsectioncount 1;
        content: counter(sectioncount) "-" counter(subsectioncount) " ";
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>    
    <h1>Section1</h1>
    <h2>SubSection 1</h2>
    <h2>SubSection 2</h2>        
    <h1>Section2</h1>
    <h2>SubSection 1</h2>
    <h2>SubSection 2</h2>    
</body>
```

but the subsection counter does not increment. I can't figure out why and how to fix this. The question is : what is the proper way to achieve this in CSS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, I don't know exactly why, but in this case setting counters for host elements (not pseudo elements) fixes your issue:

```css
/**
  @note 2021-09 this rule is not necessary and
    ⚠ at this moment breaks subsequent resets in Firefox ⚠
  @see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1729498
*/
body {
  counter-reset: sectioncount subsectioncount;
}

h1 {
  counter-increment: sectioncount 1;
  counter-reset: subsectioncount;
}

h1:before {
  content: counter(sectioncount) " ";
}

h2 {
  counter-increment: subsectioncount 1;
}

h2:before {
  content: counter(sectioncount) "-" counter(subsectioncount) " ";
}
```

```html
<h1>Section1</h1>
<h2>SubSection 1</h2>
<h2>SubSection 2</h2>
<h1>Section2</h1>
<h2>SubSection 1</h2>
<h2>SubSection 2</h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS counters to do that: https://jsfiddle.net/tfechswg/3/

Here an example:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

li {
  display: block;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, "-") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Section 1
    <ol>
      <li>sub section</li>
      <li>sub section</li>
      <li>sub section</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>li section</li>
  <li>li section
    <ol>
      <li>sub section</li>
      <li>sub section</li>
      <li>sub section</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to achieve it with non-nested tags, like in the exemple I gave, with h1 and h2. As far as I understand, the counters() function appends several instances of a given counter. I would like to use distinct counters. There should be a way to do so right ?

Comment: Well that is what I did in the example I gave. But it does not work : the second counter does not increment. Maybe a bug ? Anyway we can fix it as myf explained.